# norm inequality of two square matrices nxn

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

$A$ and $B$ two square matrices with the same size $n\times n$. How can I prove the inequality below:

$$\lVert(A+B)^n-A^n\rVert\leq \lVert A\rVert\lVert B\rVert e^\frac{\lVert(B)\rVert}{\lVert(A)\rVert}$$

Comment: The inequality isn't true. When $A=I$ and $B=tI$ is small, the LHS is $nt+O(t^2)$, while the RHS is $t+O(t^2)$.